# Asto SSR generated code doesn't run on older versions of iOS

Tags: javascript, safari, svelte, ios12, astrojs

I am hosting astro SSR site on Netlify. It works well everywhere except when I test on iPhone 6 and older. Basically all script executions are stopped and the site is no longer interactive.

Errors from Safari on iPhone 5SE Simulator:

`[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`

`[Error] The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.`

`[Error] The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored. (x2)`

`[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'`

`[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'`

[image]

[image]

I am not really sure how to fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I used svelte for building astro islands and google recaptcha(v3) in the page that is being tested. The page works fine on development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you have some code using optional chaining, e.g. `object?.potentiallyMissingProperty`. Per [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining), this only works on iOS Safari versions 13.4 and later. An iPhone 6 can only install iOS 12, so using this syntax will throw an error on those devices.

This appears to be an [issue within Astro](https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/4812), which does not support some older browsers. Astro also scopes CSS with `:where`, which will also [break on older versions of Safari](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_where). On those browsers, your page's HTML should render, but any JavaScript will not work and should be treated as a progressive enhancement.